# AsyncTask not displaying popup for wrong credential

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I tried
 to make an activity for Login 
                                               and i have used AsyncTask but when 
          i try
 with the 
wrong credential it doesnt show any pop up about wrong password.I have tried with all the possibilities of validation but when it goes to the AsyncTask it matches the parameter but never posts anything.So where should i add the Alertdialog such that it matches the  result with parameter and returns.I need to get json strings also.Is it checking  in the onpostExecute method or doinbackground.I'm new to android pls help.

```
    public class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        Emp emp=new Emp();
        if(result==null && !(result.equals("0")) )
        {
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Login failed..", "Wrong credential please enter again", false);

            //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong credentials Please enter again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        List<Emp> data=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
         //   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
           // for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                emp.validstatus=json_data.getInt("validstatus");
                emp.roleid=json_data.getInt("roleid");
                emp.empid=json_data.getString("empid");
                data.add(emp);
                if (emp.validstatus==1 && emp.roleid==14)
                {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                   intent.putExtra("empid",emp.empid);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            else
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Login failed..", "Wrong credential please enter again", false);

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.e("reached","reaching");
        Log.v(TAG,"Before intent object");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
       // String[] loginVal = params[0].split(";");
       //String build="http://192.168.0.102/login.php?user_name="+params[0].split(";")[0]+"&password="+params[0].split(";")[1];
       //String build="http://192.168.1.10:8080/upstest/rest/profile/loginvalidate.sp?";
       String build= null;
        try {
            build = Util.getProperty("login_url",getApplicationContext());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String build1="username="+params[0].split(";")[0]+"&password="+params[0].split(";")[1];
        String x=build+build1;
        Log.e("the url ", x);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(x);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null)
            {
                Log.e("Data", "can't fetch");
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            Log.e("Bufferreader",String.valueOf(reader));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
           // Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
            if (!buffer.toString().contains("failed"))
            {
           //     startActivity(intent);
            return  buffer.toString();
             // finish();
            }
            else{

                return "login incorrect";
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should work , Please check whether your showAlertDialog method call and if check satisfied or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `result==null` to `result!=null` because you are returning `"login incorrect"` on login incorrect condition or login failed condition, and you are checking for `result==null` , which is not correct when you are returning any string. Result can't be null.